# Can not publish apk in play store

Tags: google-play, google-play-services

I have been facing this problem since yesterday. Although I have published an app in the play store before so I am aware of the policies. But I am trying to upload a new app in play store and it's saying me the following error,

**Check these warnings before starting the rollout of this release. Addressing the warnings on this page will ensure your existing users are able to upgrade to the latest version of your app.**

**In addition, I have tried all the way like as**

1. Removing unused code
2. Unused libraries and resources

**Furthermore, I have tried some of the previously asked questions but none of them saved my problem.**

I am adding the details of the apk in the following image,

[image]

So it would be great if someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.

**By going Analyze->Inspect Code**

This process will provide you all the unnecessary code or resources.